# making a @keyframe animation last the whole time the user stays on webpage in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how i would create a @keyframe animation that lasts the whole time that the user is on my webpage?

I have set several animations with colour on my website that are all set over a certain period of time, i would really like to know how to make these last the whole time.

Here is my current CSS;

```
@keyframes goldwhite {
    0%   {color:whie;}
    80%  {color:gold;}
    100%   {color:white;}
}

#bannerleft { 
    animation:goldwhite 2s;
    -webkit-animation:goldwhite 2s;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-2.3%;
    font-size:13px;
    color:white;
    width:130px;
    left:18%;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

So if it is possible how would i change this animation to last the whole time ?

My second question for anyone who knows is how would i create the text effect that is used on the apple IOS 7 lock screen, the part that says 'Slide to unlock' which changes effect from plane grey to silver, its hard to explane but it shows it here a little starting at 10 seconds.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ix7HnH_6cQ

Maybe this effect is on repeat ? as i would like for it to happen multiple times or once every 5 secconds .

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript/jquery to do this.

When the animation ends, you can capture the event and reset the class.   Something like this:

```
$("#MyDiv").on("webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend", 
    function ()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("bannerleft");
        $(this).addClass("bannerleft");
    });
```

Caveat...I have used the animation end events but not quite like this.  You may need to move the animation stuff to a separate class.